# is there a way I can click 2 submit buttons by clicking one of them?

Tags: javascript, html

ok this sounds weird, but i have two submit buttons.

```
</input type="submit" name="btn1" id ="btn1"/> 

</input type="submit" name="btn2" id ="btn2"/>
```

is there a way I can bind both to click together when I click one of them?

thanks.

Comment: What do you want to achieve with that? What would be the benefit?

Comment: you can add hidden fields to the first form if you trying to submit stuff that you want to hide from the user

Comment: It entirely depends on what you want to accomplish: apply a "clicked" style to the buttons, run a common JavaScript routine, submit two different forms...

Answer (score 1):

You can using javascript

follow http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml

you simply submit the second form in the function

Answer (score 1):

You can write a wrapper for the second method.

```
onclick = "CallBoth()";

onclick = "CallOne()";

function CallBoth()
{
  ...

  return CallOne();
}

function CallOne()
{
  ...
  return whatever;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[name="btn1"], input[name="btn2"]').click(function(){
        $('#myform').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

When you hit either btn1 or btn2, your form ID #myform will submit.

But the best way to do it using jQuery is using this code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.submit_form_1').click(function(){
        $('#myform').trigger('submit');
    });
});
```

and add to every button you want to use as a "submit form button for your form" the class `.submit_form_1`. Change it like you want.

Comment: THanks David.. this looks promising. Giving it a shot :)

Comment: So when you click on an object (image, button, div, whatever) who has the class "submit_form_1", the above code will run and your form with the id myform will submit.